# How can I prevent memory exhaustion using a CakePHP application?

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, memory-management

I am on a VPS server (Quad core with 768MB of RAM. I am running Apache and using APC as my default caching engine) . I get around 2000 visitors per day with a maximum of 100 concurrent visitors. 
According to CakePHP DebugKit, my most memory intensive pages use around 16MB and the other pages average at around 10MB.

- Is this memory usage normal?
- Is it normal for my memory to bottleneck at 2000 visitors per page?
- Should I consider upgrading my plan to 2GB RAM?

I also noticed that the View rendering is taking up most of the memory, around 70% on most pages.

I am monitoring my resource usage, when I have around 50 or more concurrent users, I am getting 0 free MB left.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also check your other processes. From my experience, MySQL takes up more memory than anything else on any stack that I run. You should also implement better page caching so that PHP doesn't need to be touched when it isn't absolutely necessary. But Apache is also a memory hog that needs to be fine tuned. If you want to stick with Apache, then run Varnish in front of it.

Also, keep APC, but also add Memcached. It's much faster.

If your site has a spike-load that brings it to zero memory, then, if you can, consider launching extra instances of the server and doing a sort of round-robin (if the VPS is cloud-hosted and this is possible). If the load is constant, then definitely upgrade.

@burzum is completely right, however, that you should just switch to nginx. It's far, far better than Apache at this point. But, just to put you on the right track, quite a few people run nginx as a reverse proxy in front of Apache, and while that does speed up the server, it's entirely unnecessary because nginx can do pretty much anything you need it to do without Apache. Don't bother using Varnish in front of nginx either because nginx can act as its own reverse proxy.

Your best bet is to implement nginx with apcu (upgrade php to 5.5 if possible for better performance) and use memcached, and implement nginx's native microcaching abilities. If your site is heavy on read and light on write, then you might notice that everything is taken care of by nginx just retrieving a cached copy from memcache. While this helps with memory, it also helps with processing. My servers' CPUs usually have a 3-5% usage during peaks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this memory usage normal?

Yes, it doesn't seem to be high for a normal CakePHP application.

> Is it normal for my memory to bottleneck at 2000 visitors per page?

I guess yes, I'm not a "server guy".

> Should I consider upgrading my plan to 2GB RAM?

I would try switching to Nginx first. Apache is a memory eating monster compared to Nginx, just search for a few banchmarks, a *random* one I've picked by a quick search is from [this](http://blog.webfaction.com/2008/12/a-little-holiday-present-10000-reqssec-with-nginx-2/) page.

[image]

Overall Nginx should provide you a much better performance. At some stage I would consider updating the memory but try Nginx first.